# Jquery Can't append option Filed in Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I am having problem to append `<option>` in `<select>` as my scenario is I am showing all list if users want to add their own option so I am opening model and take input from user

And problem is I am not able append user input with their specify Select option

as I have add more options to

HTML:

```
<li style="width: 27%;">
    <label class="select">
        <span style="display: inline-block;padding: 10px 0;">Institute:</span>
        <select name="institute[]" id="institue1" onchange="Myinsi(this.value, 'institue1')"  class="validate[required] institute" style="width: 65%;float: right;">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php
            $sel = "select * from institute where `status`= 'Y'";

            $res = mysql_query($sel);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                echo "<option value='{$row['title']}'>{$row['title']}</option>\n";
            }
            echo'<option value="ShowOtherIns" id="ShowOtherIns">Other</option>';
            ?>
        </select>
        <i></i>
    </label>
</li>
```

jQuery Code:

```
<script>
    function Myinsi(value, id) {
        console.log(value + '----' + id);
        var index = $(id + ' option').length + 1;
        if (value == "ShowOtherIns") {
            $('#OtherIns').modal("show");
            document.getElementById("btnSave").onclick = function () {
                var NewText = document.getElementById('OtherInsTextID').value;
                if (NewText = !'') {
                    var element = document.getElementById(id); // assuming ul exists
                    $(id).append('<option value="' + NewText + '" selected="selected">' + NewText + '</option>');
                    $('#OtherIns').modal("hide");
                } else {
                    console.log("text = exibir menu");
                }
            };
        }
    }

</script>
```

I am attaching my screen shoot too

[image]

Comment: Your selector is incorrect, Use `$(element).append('<option....)`

Comment: Satpal You are just great :) But now its showing me True in my options

Answer (score 0):

Jquery selector is incorrect. You have to write "#" followed by the id of your html element. In the line `var index = $(id + ' option').length + 1;` you should write `var index = $('#'+id + ' option').length + 1;`.

Also in the line `$(id).append('<option value="' + NewText + '" selected="selected">' + NewText + '</option>');` you should write `$('#'+id).append('<option value="' + NewText + '" selected="selected">' + NewText + '</option>');`